# SQL Server Data Tools version 17.x is available for which version of Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, powershell, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Kindly let me know where can I get 17.x version of SSDT. I am trying to run a powershell script which requires SQL Server Data Tools version 17.x. I am not sure which version of VS it's referring to? 2017 or 2015

The error message is:

> Exception calling "DeployProject" with "2" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 19-Sep-2019 07:04:28 'Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 19-Sep-2019 07:04:28 PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: **There is no SSDT 17 version**, also there is no [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History) or [SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/) 17 version

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue use powershell?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the error, since I we mentioned before there is not data tools 17.x version since the last one is 15.x . If you post the error message you are receiving and some screenshots it will be great

Comment: Please find below the error message:

Comment: Exception calling "DeployProject" with "2" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 
19-Sep-2019 07:04:28 'Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
19-Sep-2019 07:04:28 PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: @Fraz check my answer update

Comment: @Fraz then you should install ssdt for Visual studio 2015 (sql server 2016)

Answer (score 0):

As I know for Visual Studio 2017 the relevant SSDT version is 15.x And with Visual Studio 2019, the required functionality to enable Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects has moved into the respective Visual Studio extensions.

**Reference**

- [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)

---

#### Update 1

Based on your comments, you must install SSDT for SQL Server 2016 (version 14)

- [Previous releases of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT and SSDT-BI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: Could you please share the exact link to download this particular version of SSDT?

Comment: @Fraz https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2016#recent-downloads

Comment: Thanks @Hadi but still i dont see SSDT for SQL Server 2016 version 14 here

Comment: @Fraz ssdt for Visual Studio 2015

Comment: but I am using VS 2017 not 2015